# React native check if event has been removed

Tags: react-native

I am adding KeyboardEvent listeners to my react native code, like so:

```
keyboardListener = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidShow", onKeyboardShowed);
```

There are several places when I call `keyboardListener.remove()` and I would like to be able to re-add this listener **ONLY** if it has been removed.

Something like this:

```
if(keyboardListener.isRemoved){
    // Reattach the listener
    keyboardListener = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidShow", onKeyboardShowed);
}
```

Is there a way to check `keyboardListener.remove()` has been called?

Answer (score 0):

Well as of this post the `removeListener()` has been deprecated (https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboard#removelistener). There is a `.remove()` which should be appended to `addEventListener()`.

Answer (score -1):

There is no function `.remove()`, you might mean `removeListener` or `removeAllListeners` like described in the [Documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboard#removealllisteners)?!?

Comment: The documentation is wrong, `removeListener` doesn't actually work and `.remove()` on the returned subscription object needs to be used instead. I had to do a bunch of research to find this out. This is tested and works. See the doc here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.46/keyboard